# How to set up redmine to send email notification in a digest format

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redmine, digest

I'm trying to configure `redmine` to send email notifications **once a day.** I have installed a plugin: digest (https://github.com/drewkeller/redmine_digest)

I believe I followed the instruction (https://github.com/drewkeller/redmine_digest/blob/master/README.rdoc) pretty much correctly, but whenever I create a ticket the redmine still immediately sends email notification.
I want to receive a digest of notifications once a day, not every time I or someone create a ticket.

How should I correct this?

My setting for the plugin is:

```
    Default setting for users [checked] send me digest emails
    Days ago to start:1
    Days to include:1
    Output extra messages(console and log)[checked]
```

and My email notification setting is fully checked. Please help.

*More information*

```
Environment:
Redmine version                          2.3.1.stable
Ruby version                             1.8.7 (x86_64-linux)
Rails version                            3.2.13
Environment                              production
Database adapter                         MySQL
Redmine plugins:
redmine_digest                           0.2.0
```